# cut the text if overflow reached xsl fop

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have xsl. and I am using Apache FOP 0.93. In one of the table cell, I have long text.

Currently issue is, if text is too long it will overwrite the next cell value. I want to solve this. So, If long text comes, it should show text up to width, remaining should be hide.

I have tried overflow attribute in `fo:block`. somehow it's not working.

Can anyone help me out for this?

Answer (score 4):

Set overflow="hidden" on a block-container inside the table-cell. Note this will likely only work with FOP but that is what you are using:

```
        <fo:table>
        <fo:table-column column-width="1in"/>
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black">
                    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden"><fo:block>Iamtoowideforacell</fo:block></fo:block-container>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
```

Results in this:

[image]